# How can i get maven's Local respository In intellij idea plugin development

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I want to get maven's local repository in intellij idea plugin development.

```
 @Override
public void actionPerformed(AnActionEvent e) {
    logger.info("begin generator");
    Project project = e.getProject();
    /*in here ,I want to get maven's local repository*/
    if(project ==null)
        return;
    PsiJavaFile file = UtpJunitGenUtil.getSelectedJavaFile(e.getDataContext());
```

[image: Intellij Idea Settings]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a dependency on the Maven plugin (see [here](http://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/basics/plugin_structure/plugin_dependencies.html) for information on adding plugin dependencies) and use the following code:

```
MavenProjectsManager m = MavenProjectsManager.getInstance(project);
File localRepository = m.getGeneralSettings().getEffectiveLocalRepository();
```